# HTTP Status 500 does not have the property 'id'

Tags: java

I get Error Messsage when I display the ID of the customer. I have too try to change the name of the property 'id' but the came the same error with new name.

**HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error**

**type** Exception report
**message** Internal Server Error
**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception** 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model.Customer' does not have the property 'id'.

**root cause** 
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model.Customer' does not have the property 'id'.

**note** The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.1.0 logs.

**HTML:**

```html
<%@ include file="header.jspf" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Onlineshop</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  

<c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}">
<article>
 <p>${customer.id}</p>
 <p>${customer.email}</p>
 <p>test</p>
</article>
</c:forEach>

<%@ include file="footer.jspf" %>
```

**Java Class**

package de.java2enterprise.onlineshop.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
private Long id;
private String email;
private String password;

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String email, String password) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String toString() {
    return 
        "[" +
        getID() + ", " +
        getEmail() + ", " +
        getPassword() + 
        "]";
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
@WebServlet("/userShow")
```

public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Resource
private DataSource ds;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        List<Customer> customers = find();
        if (customers != null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("customers", customers);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
    }
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

public List<Customer> find() throws Exception {

    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    try (final Connection con = ds.getConnection();
            final PreparedStatement stmt = con
                    .prepareStatement(
                            "SELECT " +
                                    "id, " +
                                    "email, " +
                                    "password " +
                                    "FROM onlineshop.customer ")) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
```

Customer customer = new Customer();

```
            Long id = Long.valueOf(rs.getLong("id"));
            customer.setID(id);

            String email = rs.getString("email");
            customer.setEmail(email);

            String password = rs.getString("password");
            customer.setPassword(password);
            customers.add(customer);

        }
    }
    return customers;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you don't have a property called `id`, but instead one called `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Customer` class needs to follow the naming conventions for Java beans:

It's `getId/setId` instead of `getID/setID`.